# Release in cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This code runs good but there's something I don't understand.

Did

```
 //Release
 [_nextProjectile release];
 _nextProjectile =nil;
```

Here release and set _nextProjectile to nil after the action of _player?
If so, how did the next block work if _nextProjectile is released?

```
_nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"projectile2.png"] retain];
_nextProjectile.position = ccp(20, winSize.height/2);
...
[_player runAction:
 [CCSequence actions:
  [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
  [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
     [self addChild:_nextProjectile];
     [_projectiles addObject:_nextProjectile];

     // Release
     [_nextProjectile release];
     _nextProjectile =nil;
 }],
  nil]];

// Move projectile to actual endpoint
[_nextProjectile runAction:
 [CCSequence actions:
  [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
  [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
     [_projectiles removeObject:node];
     [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
 }],
  nil]];
```

Comment: CCSequence executes only one time. Also post your code for _nextProjectile initialisation

Comment: Thanks, I added the initialisation.

Comment: stop worrying and learn to love the ARC bomb ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will be released and set to nil when the CCCallBlockN is executed (after the rotate action).

However, while this segment of code is executed, it has not yet been released, so the  [_nextProjectile runAction ...] works because you still have a reference to it _ the first sequence has not even started yet.

The reason you must release it is because it was retained in the first place, so that the retain count drops to 0 at some point. When that happens, since the CCSprite constructor returns an auto-release object, the final wash-out and reclaiming the memory will take place at the next iteration of the main loop, when the autorelease pool is cleaned up by the obj-c runtime.